# How do I make objects created with transform effect into an actual object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, transform, flatten

Say, you apply transform as an effect and make a bunch of rotated copies of an object. Now those copies are an effect and if you center the object it will only center the original object and not the entire thing you are seeing.

How can you "flatten" the object so instead of a transform effect you have an actual object with no effect that looks like the original object with the transform effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd> on the transformed 'group'. You might need to <kbd>Object > Ungroup</kbd> the result.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure you can't "ungroup" this as it is not a grouped object, but an effect. I just had the same question and so I tried to object flatten transparency. Now, I had made my objects white on top of a black large rectangle. Now they are a grouped object and they can be manipulated as such (I applied a "subtract front" path action and it worked.)

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.